# How to resolve $q.all?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, q

I have 2 functions, both returning promises:

```
    var getToken = function() {

        var tokenDeferred = $q.defer();         
        socket.on('token', function(token) {
            tokenDeferred.resolve(token);
        });
        //return promise
        return tokenDeferred.promise;
    }

    var getUserId = function() {
        var userIdDeferred = $q.defer();
        userIdDeferred.resolve('someid');           
        return userIdDeferred.promise;
    }
```

Now I have a list of topics that I would like to update as soon as these two promises get resolved

```
    var topics = {      
        firstTopic: 'myApp.firstTopic.',  
        secondTopic: 'myApp.secondTopic.',
        thirdTopic: 'myApp.thirdTopic.',
        fourthTopic: 'myApp.fourthTopic.',
    };
```

Resolved topics should look like this `myApp.firstTopic.someid.sometoken`

```
var resolveTopics = function() {
    $q.all([getToken(), getUserId()])
    .then(function(){

        //How can I resolve these topics in here?

    });
}
```

Comment: They will be resolved by the time code before/after your comment is executed. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all Are you asking how to get the returned data from each? that's also answered in the documentation at the above link. The first aregument will be an array with values that represent what the promises were resolved with.

Comment: I am sorry I will edit. I am asking how to update `topics` with values that are returned by getToken() and getUserId()

Comment: How is topics related to the data being returned from getToken and getUserId promises?

Comment: myApp.firstTopic.someid.sometoken

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$q.all` creates a promise that is automatically resolved when all of the promises you pass it are resolved or rejected when *any* of the promises are rejected.

If you pass it an array like you do then the function to handle a successful resolution will receive an array with each item being the resolution for the promise of the same index, e.g.:

```
  var resolveTopics = function() {
    $q.all([getToken(), getUserId()])
    .then(function(resolutions){
      var token  = resolutions[0];
      var userId = resolutions[1];
    });
  }
```

I personally think it is more readable to pass `all` an object so that you get an object in your handler where the values are the resolutions for the corresponding promise, e.g.:

```
  var resolveTopics = function() {
    $q.all({token: getToken(), userId: getUserId()})
    .then(function(resolutions){
      var token  = resolutions.token;
      var userId = resolutions.userId;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Even though my question is not clear, you nailed it. Thank you

Comment: FYI, the library q and $q are not the same.  As of q version 1.4.1, q.all() does not accept objects.  [However, $q does accept objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).