# q.all() to resolve multiple mongoose queries concurrently

Tags: javascript, mongoose, q

I am trying to use the q promise library to run two mongoose queries concurrently. I wish to make the two queries independently, then execute a function using the results after both queries are complete.

I attempted to set up q.all() this way, but the result is always state pending in the `then()`.  I need resolved query results instead of pending promises.

```
var q = require('q');

var promises = {
    aircraft: q(aircraftModel.findOne({_id: tailNumber})
        .exec()),
    faaAircraft: q(faaAircraftModel.findOne({_id: tailNumber.substring(1)})
        .exec())
};

q.all(promises).then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
}, function(err){
    console.log(err)
})
```

The result is the object of pending promises below, not values.  How can I get values returned from MongoDB for these queries?

```
{ aircraft: { state: 'pending' },
  faaAircraft: { state: 'pending' } }
```

The `function(err){}` is never executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, `q.all()` only handles arrays of promises, not objects of promises (like you're passing). Also, since Mongoose's `.exec()` returns a promise already, you don't have to wrap them using `q(...)` (although it doesn't hurt if you do).

Try this:

```
var promises = [
  aircraftModel.findOne({_id: tailNumber}).exec(),
  faaAircraftModel.findOne({_id: tailNumber.substring(1)}).exec()
];

q.all(promises).then(...);
```

Comment: Changing the `q.all()` argument to an array causes my code to work.  For some reason this answerer thinks objects are possible... not sure why he thinks this.    http://stackoverflow.com/a/24396588/404699  Perhaps q and $q are different libraries.

Comment: @steampowered `$q` is an Angular service that is _inspired_ by `q`, but it's not the same :-) (it [indeed](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) accepts objects too).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using `q` on newer releases of Node is to use the native [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method with mongoose's [mpromise](https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise):

```
var promises = [
  aircraftModel.findOne({_id: tailNumber}).exec(),
  faaAircraftModel.findOne({_id: tailNumber.substring(1)}).exec()
];

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going this route.  I prefer to use native functionality unless I need another library.