# Pass object literal with promises to Q.all()

Tags: javascript, promise, q

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396413/how-to-resolve-q-all), the Angular promise library `$q` can take in an object containing a bunch of promises, and in the `.then()` function, you can retrieve the results using the object keys:

```
$q.all({
    result1: foo(),
    result2: bar()
})
.then(function(results) {
    var fooData = results.result1;
    var barData = results.result2;
});
```

Is such a thing possible with the regular [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library? How can I do it on my Node.js app?

Comment: [Nope, doesn't seem to](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination)

Comment: This is a question that can be answered by looking at the documentation of the repo that you linked to, or by writing the code and seeing if it works.

Comment: You could try [`Promise.props`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html) or [`Promise.join`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) from Bluebird

Comment: @Phil - why would OP load bluebird if they already have q?

Comment: you can always do `$q.all(Object.values({
    result1: foo(),
    result2: bar()
}))`

Comment: @JaromandaX was just a suggestion for a library offering the API OP wanted. Presumably OP wants the promise to resolve with an object that has the keys `result1`, `result2` (as it would with Angular's `$q`). Using `Object.values` wouldn't do that

Comment: @Phil I actually like the Bluebird solution, I swapped it out and nothing seems to have broken :)

Comment: @AlexWohlbruck yeah, Bluebird's pretty good. In tests, it's more performant than vanilla promises too

Comment: @Phil - where are these "tests"? I've read the same claim, but have never seen any proof of this "more performant" claim

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, should have prefaced that with *"or so I've heard"* :) Source of the rumour here ~ http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird

Comment: ahh, you too :p

Comment: @JaromandaX tests! https://jsperf.com/native-promises-vs-bluebird-promises/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always build this with just a few lines of code:

```
function all( object ){
    if(Array.isArray( object )) 
        return $q.all( object );

    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    return $q.all(keys.map(key => object[key]))
        .then(values => values.reduce((acc, value, index) => {
            acc[keys[index]] = value;
            return acc;
        }, {}));
}
```

Comment: `Q` promises don't have a `reduce` method. I suppose you forgot a `then`?